# Double char - python

Tags: python, character

The points is from a certain input for example "Hello World" I need to print each character(case-sensitive) is repeated twice.
It should look like this "HHeelllloo WWoorrlldd".

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site because SO isn't a free online coding service. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
s = "Hello World"
print("".join(x*2 if x != " " else x for x in s ))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'HHeelllloo WWoorrlldd'
```

I received a comment highlighting the fact that spaces do not need to be doubled - hence `if x != " " else x` has been added. If that is not the case - you want to double spaces as well:

```
"".join(x*2 for x in s )
```

Answer (score 1):

This works great and is readable.

```
string = "Hello World"
final = ""
for char in string:
   final += char*2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inp = input()
print(''.join(c + c for c in inp))
```

Comment: I think there should be a check to avoid space. In the OP expected output only contains single space.